# Using std::complex with iPhone's vDSP functions

Tags: iphone, c++, c, vdsp

I've been working on some vDSP code and I have come up against an annoying problem.  My code is cross platform and hence uses std::complex to store its complex values.

Now I assumed that I would be able to set up an FFT as follows:

```
DSPSplitComplex dspsc;
dspsc.realp = &complexVector.front().real();
dspsc.imagp = &complexVector.front().imag();
```

And then use a stride of 2 in the appropriate vDSP_fft_* call.

However this just doesn't seem to work.  I can solve the issue by doing a vDSP_ztoc but this requires temporary buffers that I really don't want hanging around.  Is there any way to use the vDSP_fft_* functions directly on interleaved complex data?  Also can anyone explain why I can't do as I do above with a stride of 2?

Thanks

**Edit:** As pointed out by Bo Persson the real and imag functions don't actually return a reference.

However it still doesn't work if I do the following instead

```
DSPSplitComplex dspsc;
dspsc.realp = ((float*)&complexVector.front()) + 0;
dspsc.imagp = ((float*)&complexVector.front()) + 1;
```

So my original question still does stand :(

Comment: @Mat: the vDSP_fft_* call returns incorrect data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The std::complex functions `real()` and `imag()` return by value, they do not return a reference to the members of complex.

This means that you cannot get their addresses this way.

Comment: Ahhh hadn't noticed that!  Cheers!  So it wouldn't work anyway ... bugger.

Comment: According to C++11 you should be able to cast a pointer to a std::complex into a pointer to an array of two floats (or doubles). We don't know if that works with earlier compilers though.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it.

`const COMPLEX *in = reinterpret_cast<const COMPLEX*>(std::complex);`

Source: http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html

EDIT:
To clarify the source; COMPLEX and fftw_complex use the same data layout (although fftw_complex uses `double` and COMPLEX `float`)

Comment: What has FFTW got to do with vDSP?

Comment: COMPLEX and fftw_complex use the same data layout (although fftw_comples uses doubles and COMPLEX floats). I have verified this cast and it works with the vDSP_* functions.

Comment: Absoloutely not.  `DSPSplitComplex` is required by the `vDSP_fft_*` functions and is a non-interleaved format.  `std::complex` and FFTW's `COMPLEX` are both interleaved.  Sure you can use `vDSP_ctoz`/`vDSP_ztoc` but the whole point of this question is to avoid doing this.

Comment: My comment is correct, the types `COMPLEX` and `fftw_complex` represent the same data layout. However, I misunderstood your question. I'm well aware that `vDSP_fft_*` needs `COMPLEX_SPLIT` (DSPSplitComplex) and `vDSP_ctoz`. I guess one workaround for you could be to use fftw instead of Accelerate since it would allow you to use an interleaved layout. They perform similary for small inputs. Benchmark: https://gist.github.com/admsyn/3452792

Comment: Except I either need to buy a license for FFTW or GPL my commercial iPhone based products.  As such thats really not a useful suggestion.

Comment: And that license is $15,000!! http://technology.mit.edu/technologies/15054_fastest-fourier-transform-in-the-west-fftw-version-3-3-x-fftw-v-3-3-x

Comment: This is another one I'm aware of (BSD license) but I'm not sure which data layout it uses since I've never used it. https://github.com/anthonix/ffts paper here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ihw/papers/13-AMB-IHW-MJC-FastFourier.pdf

Comment: And while FFTS is very interesting it has no ARM64 support so cannot be used on an iPhone app.

Comment: Ok.. Seems to have some iOS build scripts..? Are those only optimized for older ARM architectures?

Comment: There is no straight C implementation and it relies heavily on SIMD assembly which is pretty different between 32-bit and 64-bit ARM processors.  I'm sure it could be converted to 64-bit assembly but its a significant change and I do not have the time to do it.